# Prolog counting knowledge base

Tags: count, prolog

I have something like this in my knowledge base:

```
number(1).
number(3).
number(6).
number(8).
number(9).
number(12).
```

Now, I need a predicate that evaluates how many numbers there are in the knowledge base, example:

```
countnumbers(X).
X = 6.
```

How can I do this? please, I'm new with prolog and I can't figure this out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `findall/3` to get all facts from your database, and then get the length of the list:

```
countnumbers(X) :-
    findall(N, number(N), Ns),
    length(Ns, X).
```

Take care: `number/1` may be a built-in predicate.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to know how many `X` satisfied some predicate you don't need to know all of them. Using of `findall/3` is really redundant in tasks like that. When you have 6 or 606 these `X` - it's not a big deal of course. But when you have really large and heavy generator - you don't need to keeping all values in list and then counting it length.

`Aggregate` solves this problem well:

```
numberr(1).
numberr(3).
numberr(6).
numberr(8).
numberr(9).
numberr(12).

countNumbers( Numbers ) :-
    aggregate( count, X^numberr( X ), Numbers ).
```

`X^` means "there exists X", so the whole formula means something like "count the number X that `numberr(X)` and call that number `Numbers`.

So

```
?- countNumbers(X).
X = 6.
```

Comment: If you had looked into aggregate.pl, you'd seen that `aggregate/3` calls `bagof/3` and then `length/2` on the result. So what exactly have we won in terms of execution speed?

Comment: @twinterer, you are referring to a particular implementation, Dimitrii is referring to the interface. The implementation may improve without changing the interface. However, a program which uses the list explicitly has no chances to profit from a better implementation. One of the reason why libraries do not improve as much as they could is because they are not used. Instead, people reinvent everything.

Comment: @false: quite true. But I think the only chance to make this substantially quicker is to implement the library not through Prolog built-ins, as it is currently done. Slim hope, I think. Currently, the argument to use `aggregate/3` in favour of `findall/3`+`length/2` doesn't hold. If I really was worried about runtime, though, then I can save 25% runtime over both versions (by my tests) by using a global variable as counter and use `(n(_),incval(count),fail;getval(count,C))`. This is the only way I can think of that really gets rid of any list.

Comment: Using a global variable `count` does not work, because it does not nest.  But I agree with you that some mechanism of that kind is needed - somehow. But this can be hidden behind `aggregate/3`. The same applies also to setof/3: Repeated solutions could be withheld immediately. Or: Maybe only if they occur immediately one after the other... In any case, that is the responsibility of a library implementor, not the library user.

Comment: Is there a way to make a distinct count? Like for example if we have two times the same number,not to count it again